# Set CType Control ID with a variable

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am writing a small Sub Routine so it populates DropDownLists dynamically.

However, when it comes to passing the Control ID using a variable I am unsure if I have set up my parameters correctly. It's used to generate DropDownLists using 24 hour time i.e. sHH

The problem is here:

```
fName = CType(ctrl.FindControl("sHH"), DropDownList)
```

The sHH I need to be the same value as fName. I have tried to concatenate:

```
fName = CType(ctrl.FindControl("'" & sHH & "'"), DropDownList)
```

This is the error I get when I do the above:

> Operator '&' is not defined for types 'String' and 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList'.

Start Hours (07 to 21)
Start Minutes (00 to 45)

End Hours (07 to 21)
End Minutes (00 to 45)

I was forced to add:

```
    Private Property sHH As DropDownList
    Private Property sMM As DropDownList
    Private Property eHH As DropDownList
    Private Property eMM As DropDownList
```

Here is my declaration:

```
    'Populate arrays
    Dim ddlHours() As Integer = {"07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21"}
    Dim ddlQuarter() As Integer = {"00", "15", "30", "45"}

    popDDL(sHH, FormView1, ddlHours, 3)
    popDDL(sMM, FormView1, ddlQuarter, 1)
    popDDL(eHH, FormView1, ddlHours, 3)
    popDDL(eMM, FormView1, ddlQuerter, 1)
```

Here is my Sub Routine:

```
Public Sub popDDL(ByVal fName As DropDownList, ByRef ctrl As Control, ByVal iDDL() As Integer, Optional ByVal OpLoopTo As Integer = 0)
    'Find the control
    fName = CType(ctrl.FindControl("sHH"), DropDownList)

    'Loop through the length of iDDL items
    For i As Integer = 0 To iDDL.Length - 1

        'Loops through optional value so that I can add leading zeros if necessary
        If OpLoopTo > -1 Then

            Dim j As Integer = 0

            If j < OpLoopTo Then
                j += 1
                'Add Leading zeros to the first values
                fName.Items.Add(iDDL(i).ToString("D2"))
            Else
                'No leading for the remaining
                fName.Items.Add(iDDL(i))
            End If
        Else
            fName.Items.Add(iDDL(i))
        End If

    Next
End Sub
```

I've only been doing .NET for a little over a week and I'm unsure if I have set my parameters correctly.

Any Ideas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My apologies, it wasn't even difficult. I walked away and came back with fresh eyes.

I created an additional parameter called fieldID as string

Declaration:

```
popDDL(sHH, "sHH", FormView1, ddlHours, 3)
```

Function parameters and usage:

```
Public Sub popDDL(ByVal fName As DropDownList, ByRef fieldID As String, ByRef ctrl As Control, ByVal iDDL() As Integer, Optional ByVal OpLoopTo As Integer = 0)
        'Find the control
        fName = CType(ctrl.FindControl(fieldID), DropDownList)
```

Sorry for any wasted time.

Comment: Its good you worked it out... sometimes these things come at you in a flash. Could you mark this as your answer so that is shows as answered.

Comment: I can only mark my own answer as correct after two days I'm afraid.

Comment: I didn't know that... shows how many times I've managed to answer my own question.